# Make a tiny arrow move left to right as user scrolls up and down page

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm looking to incrementally move/slide a small arrow shaped element from left to right as the user scrolls up and down the page.

For example if i scroll down 20px the arrow moves to the right 5px
and if i scroll up 40px the arrow moves to the left 10px

My site navigation will also use smooth scroll page jumps, so the arrow needs to respond and position itself to the navigated menu heading(such as a default pixel location for each nav link).

Can anyone provide direction and best coding for this?

Thanks

```
.arrow {
enter code here  width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 6px solid transparent;
border-right: 6px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 5px solid #7AC943;
position:relative;
margin-top: -5px;
margin-left: 41px;
position: fixed;
}

.arrow:after {
content:'';
position:absolute;
top:2px;
left:-5px;
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-left: 5px solid transparent;
border-right: 5px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 4px solid black;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? CSS code?

Comment: Add few of your code..to start with ..wat have triedd...

Comment: I've just completed the design but I am now beginning to code it. I will try with what I've learned so far as my experience is very elementary but I will give it a shot and update my question in the coming days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically all the jQuery code you need

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $('.arrow').css('margin-left',$(this).scrollTop() / 4 + 'px');
});
```

Bind to the window scroll event and change the position of the arrow accordingly

To make the arrow always visible you'd need to use `position:fixed;`

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A5YvF/)**

Comment: This worked. But a few things now is the arrow jumps to the left at first and then proceeds to the right as intended. Also it goes too far to the right and if i increase the pixel value it doesn't go far enough. So is possible to define a fixed area or a max distance in the jquery syntax you've provided or some other method to make it work?